# The length of a StringBuffer is part of its capacity?

Tags: java

```
StringBuffer theString = new StringBuffer("0123456789ABCDEF");
```

In this case:

length = 16

capacity = 32

---

but if I append 16 more chracters:

```
theString.append("0123456789ABCDEF");
```

length = 32
capacity = 32

---

So I'm a little confused, it's possible to use the complete buffer (as I think it happened when I add the additional 16 characters) or the buffer is never reached because it's always apart from the length?

Comment: This is explained in the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what java API for StringBuffer, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html,  says "Every string buffer has a capacity. As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string buffer does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer array. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger." Hence if you add more characters, it will increase capacity as needed and grow.

Answer (score 0):

When you created StringBuffer object called theString. Java will allocate you 32 chracter capacity. If length of object exceeds 32 it add more 32 characters so capacity will become 64 likewise. so you will get 32 capacity untill your character lrngth is less than 32

Answer (score 0):

When you initialising your string buffer what happens is it constructs a string buffer initialized to the contents of the specified string. The initial capacity of the string buffer is 16 plus the length of the string argument. So you are initialising string buffer with 16 chars, capacity would be 16+16=32. So it means that when you appending 16 chars more there is no need to extend the capacity. Check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer-java.lang.String-).